# How to omit NoneType from Web2Py URLs with get vars

Tags: python, dictionary, web2py, nonetype

I know if can be accomplished with a few if statements and repeated code, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to handle this seeing as it's in my view and I don't like to have large code blocks in them.
I have two buttons, Print and CSV. The URLs they link to are set up like the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('teacher', 'classdata', args=request.args, vars={'view':'print', 'header':header, 'student':student})}}" target="_blank">Print</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('teacher', 'classdata', args=request.args, vars={'view':'csv', 'header':header, 'student':student})}}" target="_blank">Download CSV</a>
```

The problem I'm having here is that both student and header can be None, but they can't both not be None, and I'm looking for a one-liner solution to the problem. Like I said, I'm aware I can just make some if/else blocks like:

```
{{if student:}}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('teacher', 'classdata', args=request.args, vars={'view':'print', 'student':student})}}" target="_blank">Print</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('teacher', 'classdata', args=request.args, vars={'view':'csv', 'student':student})}}" target="_blank">Download CSV</a>
{{elif header:}}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('teacher', 'classdata', args=request.args, vars={'view':'print', 'header':header})}}" target="_blank">Print</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('teacher', 'classdata', args=request.args, vars={'view':'csv', 'header':header})}}" target="_blank">Download CSV</a>
{{else:}}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('teacher', 'classdata', args=request.args, vars={'view':'print'})}}" target="_blank">Print</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('teacher', 'classdata', args=request.args, vars={'view':'csv'})}}" target="_blank">Download CSV</a>
{{pass}}
```

But that looks awful for a view. If there's nothing more concise, bummer, I can roll with that, but I'd prefer something one or two lines that I can take with me to the next time this is a thing

Comment: I would introduce a variable that takes the value `, 'student':student`, `, 'header':header` or `''` (empty). Do the test first and then construct the strings you need with the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to filter out the `None` values:

```
vars={k:v for k,v in [('view', 'print'), ('header', header), ('student', student)] if v is not None}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly the kind of solution I was thinking of, thanks!